# Add changeset to preload

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to add a changeset in a preloaded map in case no preload was found, but can't figure out how to insert the changeset; any idea?

My changeset is printed out, but no sign of it in IO.inspect(item)...

```
def select(conn, %{"list_id" => list_id}) do
  list = Repo.get!(List, list_id)
  list_id = list.id
  query  = from l in Learnit.Itemlist, where: l.list_id == ^list_id  # Filter on the list's ID
  items =
    Item
    |> Repo.all()
    |> Repo.preload(itemlists: query)
    |> Enum.map(&add_changeset(&1, list_id)) # Loop through the items to add changesets if there is no itemlist yet
  render(conn, "select.html", items: items, list: list)
end

defp add_changeset(item, list_id) do
  case Enum.count(item.itemlists) do
    0 -> # There is no itemlists yet : we create the changeset
      changeset = Itemlist.changeset(%Itemlist{}, %{item_id: item.id, list_id: list_id})
      IO.inspect(changeset)
      Map.put(item, :changeset, changeset)
      IO.inspect(item)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> My changeset is printed out, but no sign of it in IO.inspect(item)...

`Map.put(item, :changeset, changeset)` doesn't change `item`, it will return a new `item`.

try:

```
new_item = Map.put(item, :changeset, changeset)
IO.inspect(new_item)
```